# Generating large adjacency matrix

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, adjacency-matrix, network-analysis

I'm trying to generate a adjacency matrix from a csv.

The csv contains 2 columns, 1 for users and 1 for projects. The two columns form a bipartite graph, where each user can be part of multiple projects or none at all, but no edges between nodes of the same set (there are no repeating entries for the same user-project pair, but there are repeated entries of the same user or projects with different combinations for pairs).

I wrote a comparison for comparing each user's project with the entire project set using Matlab and ismember(a,b). The algorithm runs iteratively through each entry. In the end, I have an adjacency matrix of size M(|users| + |user|) x (|users| + |user|).

For small entry count < 15000, it works fast, but for a sample of +15000, Matlab stalls. I initialize the adjacency matrix with a zeros matrix (zero(r,c)) and add row by row the results of ismember(a,b). But for my Matlab, a zeros matrix zero(15000,15000) almost maxes out the memory. I tried also making a zero matrix in R with that size (matrix(0, 15000, 15000)) and it also maxes out R's memory.

Is there a way to get around this? My full sample size is 597,000 rows (with ~70,000 users and ~35,000 projects) and I want to run a network analysis of it.

Also I want to keep it in matrix format and not an adjacency list because I have a max cut min flow algorithm I want to run on the results and it only works with matrices.

Updated:

The data looks like this

```
User  |  Project
382       2429
385       2838
294       2502
...       ...
```

It is taken from SourceForge using Zerlot from University of Notredame. Where each int value is a key in a SQL database.
I want to convert this affiliation data into a one-mode user-to-user adjacency matrix where each edge between users is a shared project.

Comment: The `Matrix` package handles `sparseMatrix` objects that let you store very big matrices, as long as most of the elements are 0s. Why your final matrix should be M(|users| + |projects|) x (|users| + |projects|) instead of (|user|) x (|projects|)? An user can be linked with another user? Anyway, if you provide a small example of your dataset, you could receive more useful answers.

Comment: Oops, after looking at it the matrix size should actually be M(|user| + |user| x (|user| + |user|) since I want it to be a one-mode representation of the affiliation data, where nodes are users and edges are shared projects.